# An example of a Google Web Toolkit (GWT) Create Read Update and Delete (CRUD) Application

Tags: java, gwt, crud

Hello
Does anybody know of any examples of a Google Web Took (GWT) - based Create Read Update and Delete application.
That is, an application which uses the GWT to manipulate and display the contents of a database.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT is a client side technology, so basically gives you only the UI. Any CRUD process would happen in the server side, which could be any J2EE code.

Anyway you can take a look to the [StockWatcher Example](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/create.html) which gives you a good approach to your question (you need to implement the server side storage)

Also take a look to the [RequestFactory](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html) documentation

Does it help you?

Answer (score 3):

There are not too many such examples online.
But this is how I usually do it:

Lets assume that you want to get all the contents of a certain table from the database:

1. in GreentingService.java do following:

   public interface GreentingServiceextends RemoteService
   {
       ArrayList getEverything();
   }
2. in GreentingServiceSync.java do following:

   public interface GreentingService
   {
    void getEverything(AsyncCallback callback);
   }
3. finally in GreentingServiceImpl do following:

   ```
      public class GreentingServiceIMPL extends RemoteSericeServlet implments GreentingService
      {
        public ArrayList<String> getEverything()
        {
           String query="Select * from....";
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
           Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
           Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
           //get stuff out of daatabase here and retun as an arraylist
           }
        }
   ```
4. this is how you will call this method and use the data:
   public Someclass implements EntryPoint
   {
   public void onModuleload()
   {
       SQLRunnerAsync sql = (SQLRunnerAsync) GWT.create(SQLRunner.class);
       AsyncCallback> callback = new AsyncCallback>(){

   ```
       @Override
       public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
           //do nothing

       }

       @Override
       public void onSuccess(ArrayList<String> result) {

           for(int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
                            {


           }
       }};
       sql.getEverything(callback);
   ```

   ...............
   }//onModulelOad
   }//class

Following is a great tutorial:
http://altair.cs.oswego.edu/~tenberge/tenbergen.org/misc/DB-Access-in-GWT-The-Missing-Tutorial.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This is a skeleton CRUD application, I this would be helpful for someone looking answer for the same question

http://code.google.com/p/gwtcrudapp/

Answer (score 0):

This is a web-based CRUD-Application that I've wrote for my employer over the last few years and now got permission to open-source it:

https://github.com/fhcampuswien/atom

It uses GWT for the front-end and Hibernate to persist the data in the backend. The data-structure only needs to be defined in one central place (the DomainObject classes), since both GUI and backend are written in a generic way that is not dependent on the data-structure.

I'd love to hear comments or answer questions about it if anybody finds the time to take a look.