# Gwt + AppEngine CRUD

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, crud

We're going to develop a brand new software for our customer.
While evaluating different technologies, the most interesting I found is Google App Engine cloud service. This will keep all the system engineering complexity management out of my mind I think. The price is more work on the code: the eventual consistency of the datastore, and so on.

Google Web Toolkit looks as the best companion to GAE, too. I just deployed an hello world.

Usually, when I'm going deep in a new technology, I write a simple CRUD for a table with a few simple fields. Here's what I think I will need:

- JDO / JPA or something like Objectify /Twig "entity" class (my domain model)
- Gwt-RPC knowledge, I mean, for example, do I need DTOs?

Can anyone address me in the right direction? Or better, a good crud example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question's been answered already. I like the stockwatcher tutorial also. It will also show you how to migrate to GAE once you're done.

[An example of a Google Web Toolkit (GWT) Create Read Update and Delete (CRUD) Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064419/an-example-of-a-google-web-toolkit-gwt-create-read-update-and-delete-crud-app)

Comment: I'll look at that, but my question was also: do I need DTO + entity classes, or is there a way to use (e.g.) jdo objects as dto in a gwt+gae environment?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of examples created by me, hope it helps,

http://code.google.com/p/gwtcrudapp/